# akka and testkit. Can't get actor children

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have an actor with receive method:

```
def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Tick =>
        val child = context.system.actorOf(...) // create actor
        context.watch(child)
        child ! something

    case AskRunningJobs =>
      log.info(s"My children: ${context.children.toList.length}")
      log.info(s"My children: ${context.children.toList.map(_.path.toSerializationFormat).mkString(" ||| ")}")
      sender ! RunningJobs(context.children.toList.length)

    case unknown =>
      log.warning(s"unknown message: $unknown")
  }
```

I have detailed log output and I can clearly see that children are created and they are running. But

```
context.children.toList.length
```

is always zero. Why?
I'm running my actor using TestKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating children this way

```
val child = context.system.actorOf(...) // create actor
```

you make the created actors children of the guardian (i.e. you lose the context). Only your top-level actors are supposed to be created this way.

To make them children of your actor, you need to use

```
val child = context.actorOf(...) // create actor
```

instead. More info on actor creation can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html).